# How can i fix this shell error for the command to enable googles duet ai?

Tags: google-ai-platform

I am currently trying to do a google duet ai course. I this course the first lab task is to create an app with duet ai. The problem i have is the following step : Enable the Cloud AI Companion API for Duet AI:gcloud services enable cloudaicompanion.googleapis.com --project ${PROJECT_ID}

when i enter this command i always get the following error message :

ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) argument --project: expected one argument
Usage: gcloud services enable [SERVICE ...] [optional flags]
optional flags may be  --async | --help

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
gcloud services enable --help

Does somebody know what to do, i already tried to replace the PROJECT_ID with the actual project id but this dint work either.